# Add link to calendar page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, calendar, hyperlink

I have been trying to pore through the calendar module code and cannot figure out how to do this.  It doesn't really help that I don't understand what half of the code is calling for as I am not a programmer.

Please check out my issue here.  http://drupal.org/node/705350

Comment: Bad form to not write the question here, please edit your question and post the whole thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Within the "Basic Settings" block of the views page, click "Header: None" and add some HTML for the link (Make sure the selected input format supports anchors - to be safe, use "Full HTML"). This will appear above the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Also, click on Theme: Information link in Views editing of Calendar, and you will see all theming files for these...